# Transform camera- to world-coordinates

Tags: python, camera-calibration, coordinate-transformation, realsense

I am using a Intel Realsense D415 camera to measure the distance to objects and get the corresponding 3D-coordinates. The coordinates I am getting are accurate but I get problems when I try to transform them to another coordinate-system.

What I am trying to do is:

1. Find an object in the RGB-Frame
2. Get the depth of the object and calculate the 3D-Position relative to the camera (This has to be done because the camera has it's origin on the left stereo-camera)
3. Calculate the 3D-position into a world coordinate-system to make them useful for another application

Step 1 and 2 are working properly. My problem is in step 3. I am using *rs2_deproject_pixel_to_point* to get the right coordinates. My understanding is that I could calibrate something like a second extrinsic matrix and transform the points in the new system with:

`P_world = R * P_Camera + t = Rt * P_Camera`

with `Rt` as a 3x4 matrix and `P_Camera` as a 4x1 vector

To get the matrix *Rt* I printed a chessboard and placed it at a known position in my world-coordinates. As the origin I choose the corner of my table. Now I am searching for the chessboard in the RGB-frame and save the 3D-camera-coordinates from the depth-frame. After this step I am trying to solve the matrix with 12 linear equations from 4 points with different X,Y,Z-values and the known positions of the corners. So far so good but the results I get are nowhere near correct and I have no idea what's the mistake.

Is the mistake in the method itself or is it just my implementation that leads to wrong values? Is there any way to easily transform the coordinates in another system?

Below is the code I use to find the chessboard and get the 3D-positions:

```
def convert_depth_to_phys_coord_using_realsense(x, y, depth, cameraInfo):
    _intrinsics = rs.intrinsics()
    _intrinsics.width = cameraInfo.width
    _intrinsics.height = cameraInfo.height
    _intrinsics.ppx = cameraInfo.ppx
    _intrinsics.ppy = cameraInfo.ppy
    _intrinsics.fx = cameraInfo.fx
    _intrinsics.fy = cameraInfo.fy
    # _intrinsics.model = cameraInfo.distortion_model
    _intrinsics.model  = rs.distortion.none
    _intrinsics.coeffs = [i for i in cameraInfo.coeffs]
    result = rs.rs2_deproject_pixel_to_point(_intrinsics, [x, y], depth)
    # result[0]: right, result[1]: down, result[2]: forward
    return result[0], -result[1], -result[2]

...

# Setup the pipeline
pipe = rs.pipeline()
cfg = rs.config()
cfg.enable_stream(rs.stream.depth, 1280, 720, rs.format.z16, 30)
cfg.enable_stream(rs.stream.color, 1280, 720, rs.format.bgr8, 30)
profile = pipe.start(cfg)

# Setup the 'High Accuracy'-mode
depth_sensor = profile.get_device().first_depth_sensor()
preset_range = depth_sensor.get_option_range(rs.option.visual_preset)
for i in range(int(preset_range.max)):
    visulpreset = depth_sensor.get_option_value_description(rs.option.visual_preset,i)
    print('%02d: %s'%(i,visulpreset))
    if visulpreset == "High Accuracy":
        depth_sensor.set_option(rs.option.visual_preset, i)
# enable higher laser-power for better detection
depth_sensor.set_option(rs.option.laser_power, 180)
# lower the depth unit for better accuracy and shorter distance covered
depth_sensor.set_option(rs.option.depth_units, 0.0005)

# Skip first frames for auto-exposure to adjust
for x in range(5):
    pipe.wait_for_frames()

while(1):

    # Stores next frameset
    frameset = pipe.wait_for_frames()
    color_frame = frameset.get_color_frame()
    depth_frame = frameset.get_depth_frame()

    if color_frame:
        color = np.asanyarray(color_frame.get_data())
        depth = np.asanyarray(depth_frame.get_data())

        # Create alignment primitive with color as its target stream:
        align = rs.align(rs.stream.color)
        frameset = align.process(frameset)

        # Update color and depth frames:
        colorizer = rs.colorizer()
        aligned_depth_frame = frameset.get_depth_frame()
        colorized_depth = np.asanyarray(colorizer.colorize(aligned_depth_frame).get_data())

        # termination criteria
        criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

        # processing
        # resize the image to match the size of the depth-frame
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(color, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        resize = cv2.resize(gray,(1280,720))

        # Find the chessboard corners
        ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(resize, (rows, columns), None)
        #corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)

        if ret:
            detected = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(resize, (7,9), corners, ret)
            for corner in corners:
                x,y = corner.ravel()

                dist = aligned_depth_frame.get_distance(x, y)
                camera_info = aligned_depth_frame.profile.as_video_stream_profile().intrinsics

                x_w, y_w, z_w = convert_depth_to_phys_coord_using_realsense(x, y, dist, camera_info)
```

Comment: Your math is correct. Where is the code for rs2_deproject_pixel_to_point?

Comment: It's a method from the pyrealsenselib for the camera. Here is the link to github https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/5e73f7bb906a3cbec8ae43e888f182cc56c18692/include/librealsense2/rsutil.h#L46
Could it be a problem that all of the 4 known points share the same z-value?